# How to extract file path from between words?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

for every row in a column in a pandas frame, I have massive amount of text.

Out of that text I want to extract a file path into a separate column.

Example current df:

```
col1
Currently run file: path/to/file/file.csv -> text...
```

In every row of this column, I want to extract the file path between `'Currently run file'` and before the `' ->'`.

new df looks like this;

```
col1                                                          new_col
Currently run file: path/to/file/file.csv -> text...          path/to/file/file.csv
```

The way I am trying this now is like so:

```
df['col1'].apply(lambda st: st[st.find("Currently run file:")+1:st.find("->")])
```

which gives me output:

```
urrently executing file: path/to/file/file.csv
```

I am not sure why this method is not grabbing only file path, how do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not `+1` should be your string length

```
df['col1'].apply(lambda st: st[st.find("Currently run file:")+19:st.find("->")])
Out[17]: 
0     path/to/file/file.csv 
Name: col1, dtype: object
```